# A simple program, or - reflection, serialization, type erasure etc?

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, dry, idioms

I need to do some kind of profiling (let's not go into the details) for a certain function, on various inputs and in various external conditions. The function is "pure", i.e. has no (intentional) side-effects, doesn't use globals etc; also, let's assume for simplicity of this question that its parameters are simple; say, C-like fundamental types, plain structs or `restrict`ed pointers.

So, I've been thinking I need is to write me a small program which:

- Determines, using the command line, what the function's inputs should be; and where the files containing longer inputs are. (Let's assume long inputs' file format is a straight up binary dump from memory, no fancy textual format.)
- Read the relevant files into memory.
- Invoke the function with the appropriate arguments.
- Write the outputs to files, or check them against expected outputs I've also read from files.

This is not hard of course, but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel:

- I'm essentially "sublimating" the act of invoking a function. I'm sure in some higher-level languages this whole affair is a one-liner.
- I would be doing de-serialization and serialization of a function's parameters. Surely some libraries do that?
- If I don't hard-code the function I call, I would also have to somehow encode parameter types, or alternatively pass them in a type-erased fashion, and other such reflection bread-and-butter.
- I would expect unit-test frameworks to offer this kind of functionality. I mean, what I've described is a kind of a unit test of an (almost) arbitrary function, with inputs coming from disk and from the command-line instead of where they would normally come from in a larger system.

My question: Should I just not worry about it, and go ahead and write this program? Or should I, instead, be more of a "smart-ass" and try to rummage through existing libraries for pieces of what I'm trying to do?

Note: I'm specifically limited to C++14, but your answer can make any assumption you like about the language standard version.